# Grails querying model containing an enum set

Tags: grails, model, enums, querying

My domain class is

```
class RoomWantedAd{
    Set<MateAgeRange> mateAgeRanges
    static hasMany=[mateAgeRanges :MateAgeRange]
}
```

Her MateAgeRange is :

```
enum MateAgeRange {
    TWENTIES('18-29')
    ,THIRTIES('30-39')
    ,FOURTIES("40-49")
    ,FIFTIES("50-59")
    ,SIXTIES("60+")



final String value

private MateAgeRange(String value) {
    this.value = value
}

String toString() { value }
String getKey() { name() }


static belongsTo=[roomWanted:RoomWanted]
}
```

My problem is searching. In the search page, a person can select 0 or more values in [18-29, 30-39, 40-49, 50-59, 60+]. In the db, 0 or more values among [18-29, 30-39, 40-49, 50-59, 60+] are stored in field 'mateAgeRanges'. 
Let db contains [30-39, 50-59] in 'mateAgeRange' field. Let in the search page, the user selects [18-29, 50-59, 60+]. Then the Ad corresponding to the above list must be returned. This is because at least one value in user's selection is present in the db list. How is it possible. Is it possible using an SQL query or grails GORM query.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use exactly the same `<g:select/>` tag as you are using for create/update. Thus, you will see human readable values like `THIRTIES` in browser, but in the background the `'30-39'` values will be used.

Comment: Search page UI is okay. UI and values are working fine. My question is about querying. How this problem is queried.

Comment: don't get it. You query based on the data you get from the form. What else do you need here?

Comment: I actually would like to know the sql query corresponding to this problem

Comment: activate sql logging in DataSource.groovy: `hibernate {
  cache.use_second_level_cache = true
  cache.use_query_cache = false
  show_sql=true
  format_sql=true
}`